# How to pass PHP variable to colorbox?

Tags: php, javascript, modal-dialog, colorbox

I have a php-variable called '$id'.

When I click on a link a [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) modal-window shows up.

The problem is that I need access to my PHP variable '$id' inside of my colorbox modal-window. That access has been broken.

This is my link that fires up [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)'s modal-window when clicked on:

```
$profile['button1'] = '<a class="pm_link" href="#">'.PROFILE_SEND_MESSAGE.'</a>';
```

This is my [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)-script that gets executed when I click on my link:

```
$(".pm_link").colorbox($.extend(defaults, {
        initialWidth:'348',
        initialHeight:'348',
        innerWidth:'348',
        innerHeight:'348',
        href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/includes/forms/pm_form.php",

        onComplete: function(){
            $("#cboxLoadedContent").appendTo("#cboxContent");

            var title = 'Send Message';
            $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
        }
    }));
```

So how do I pass that php-variable to my Colorbox modal-window?

Comment: Why can't you just `echo $id;` into your generated JS code? Where in your JS code do you need the `$id`? Or how exactly do you intend to use `$id`?

Comment: $id is used inside of the form that gets loaded via Colorbox-modal window. The form that will be loaded is the file pm_form.php. There I need the $id-variable. As you can see my form gets loaded in this line:         href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/includes/forms/pm_form.php",
Hope this helps...I forgot to mention that I have almost no experience with jQuery / AJAX.:(

Comment: that helps definitely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not pass it in the query string as follows?:

```
href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/includes/forms/pm_form.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>",
```

and in your `pm_form.php`, you can grab that id parameter using the `$_GET` global as:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Would this not work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Include the `$id` as GET-parameter of the URL:

   ```
   href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'], '/includes/forms/pm_form.php?id=', htmlspecialchars($id);?>"
   ```
2. Use the GET-parameter inside of your `pm_form.php`: just `echo $_GET['id'];` where you need it.